# Add debug print code in every function using vim

Tags: c, vim, editor

I have a huge code file and want to insert print code in every function. 
I know debugging is one option but I am new to Kernel and `kgdb` is not an easy and immediate option hence I want to use printf temporarily.

I used vim's `multiple buffers` to do this task faster, but want to know if there is any way to automate it in `.vimrc`
Here is what the final code must look like

```
void foo(int a, int b) {
    printf("Some print");
    // ...
}

int bar() {
    printf("Some print");

    // ...
}

void bleh(int b) {
    printf("Some print");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What's your exact problem: Locating the lines where to add the statement, applying the change to multiple files, or just building a custom mapping / command out of the steps?!

Comment: I simply want to put print statements in every function of a file.
Building a custom mapping is a nice idea too, but I am not looking at it on high priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one quick way to do it is in the shell:

```
find -name '*.c' | xargs vim
```

In vim, you start recording with `qq` a macro, make use of the global command

```
:g/\v\s*(void|int) \w+\([^)]*\)/normal A^Mprint("some print");
```

And then you use the wonderful `argdo` command:

```
:argdo normal @q
```

To save the changes you use:

```
:argdo normal :w^M
```

That will add `print("someprint")` to every function on the located c source code files. If you want to use the function name or the file name in the `print` statement, you can use the global command with a little complex substitution like (not tested):

```
:global /\v\s*(void|int) \w+([^)]*)/s/\v(\w+)\([^]]*\)\s* {/\=submatch(0) . '\r\t\tprint(in file.function:'. expand('%') .'.'. submatch(1) . ');'
```

Remember that ^M and ^[ are not literal strings, they are inserted with `<C-v><CR>` and `<C-v><Esc>`

Hope this help

Comment: I am being too naive,but this is what happened
I replace ^M with `<C-v><CR>` 
This is the error I got
    E492: Not an editor command: Normal A^Mprint("some print");

Comment: `<C-v>` means hold `Control` and press `v` in vim key notation and also in vim key notation `<CR>` is the enter key on your keyboard. To read more about vim key notation try the following command: `:h key-notation`

Comment: Here is how I put it in vim's command line

:g/\v\s*(void|int) \w+\([^)]*\)/Normal A _^M_ print("some print");

I am using italics with extra space on both sides for non-literal. 
I got the error: `Unmatched )`
 Can you please tell me which more non-literal strings are present in the command?
Also I wanted to know how it works, thanks a lot :)

Comment: My mistake the command is `normal`, not Normal. I update the answer to reflect this case `:global` or `:g` for short applies a command selection in this case, the selection are the lines matching the regular expression `\v\s*(void|int) \w+([^)]*)`. Don't forget to see the help of global with the command `:h g`. In this case, the `:global` command is applying the sequence of keystrokes `A^Mprint("some print");` to the matched lines.

Comment: For a more descriptive print you can use: `global /\v\s*(void|int) \w+([^)]*)/s/\v(\w+)\([^]]*\)\s* \{/\=submatch(0) . "\r\t\tprint(". '"in file->function:'. expand('%') .'->'. submatch(1) . '");'`. Use the help inside vim to learn more about the solution `:h :g` `:h :s` `:h submatch()`

Comment: I made a typo when I wrote "`:global` or `:g` for short applies a command selection" I really want to write `:global` applies a command to a selection. BTW I suggest you to see the screencasts at vimcasts.org, regards

Comment: Thanks a lot.
The command that you gave did the task, but was unable to put it inside the curly braces the pattern does not match '{'.
Instead I used this to put it inside the braces. `:g/\v^\{/normal A^Mprint("Function Name: %s",__FUNCTION__);`, it worked but it got inside structures as well. How to match pattern over multiple lines?

Comment: You should accept my answer if it helps you to resolve your problem :D I don't code in C so I don't have samples to see how extend the expression to exclude structures however I see another typo in the command. This should be the correct command: `:global /\v\s*(void|int) \w+([^)]*)/s/\v(\w+)\([^)]*\)\s*\{/\=submatch(0) . "\r\t\tprint(". '"in file->function:'. expand('%') .'->'. submatch(1) . '");'`. About matching multiple lines it's about regular expressions and you should elaborate another question.